# My else if statement using a string is not working

Tags: c++, string

after a good amount of time trying to get my else if statement to work, it just doesn't. This program keeps returning the first one, no matter what I input. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string arehap;

int main()
{
    cout << "Are you happy?" << endl;
    cin >> arehap;
    if (arehap == "Yes" || "Y")
    {
        cout << "Good." << endl;
    }
    else if (arehap == "No" || "N")
    {
        cout << "Bad." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use this:

```
if (arehap == "Yes" || arehap == "Y")
{
    cout << "Good." << endl;
}
else if (arehap == "No" || arehap == "N")
{
    cout << "Bad." << endl;
}
```

When you're using the `||` operator, you have to compare two *boolean* values. If `arehap` is equal to `"Y"`, the following statement will be `True`: `arehap == "Y"`. In that case your computer will "understand" this as `if (True || False) { /* do smth */}` and this will evaluate to `True` and the code you want to execute will be run.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in this line:

```
if (arehap == "Yes" || "Y")
```

C++ understands this as

```
if ((arehap == "Yes") || ("Y"))
```

and while the first check (`arehap == "Yes"`) might be false, the second check -- which is just `"Yes"` is always true.

This happens, because the `"Yes"` gets understood as a `char const*` -- and this pointer must obviously not be `NULL`, but point to the character `'Y'`!